# Conversion from rgb to hex using a variable from background color

Tags: javascript, variables, hex, rgb, converters

I'm trying to do a conversion from rgb to hex using a variable.

Instead of the last line I want

```
var rgbnhcp1 = rgbToHex(nhcp1)
```

And later use it to write in a div

```
document.getElementById("TextWithRgbValue").innerHTML = rgbnhcp1;
```

The problem is that you have to put ready value in the code above, like rgb 20,45,233 and not a variable to later use it to put it in a div. Could you help?

```js
// Variables - taking color property in rgb from css classes

var nhcp1 = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".nhcp1"), null).getPropertyValue('background-color');

var nhcp2 = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".nhcp2"), null).getPropertyValue('background-color');

var nhcp3 = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".nhcp3"), null).getPropertyValue('background-color');

var nhcp4 = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".nhcp4"), null).getPropertyValue('background-color');

var nhcp5 = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".nhcp5"), null).getPropertyValue('background-color');

// RGB to HEX

function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

console.log(rgbToHex(0, 51, 255)); // #0033ff
```

```css
.nhcp4 { bakground-color:teal}
.nhcp5 { bakground-color:yellow}
```

```html
<div class="nhcp1" style="background-color:red">Div 1</div>
<div class="nhcp2" style="background-color:blue">Div 2</div>
<div class="nhcp3" style="background-color:green">Div 3</div>
<div class="nhcp4">Div 4</div>
<div class="nhcp5">Div 5</div>
```

Comment: made you a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract the 3 values from the rgb(a) string

Note I ignore possible transparency

```js
// RGB to HEX
const componentToHex = c => (+c).toString(16).padStart(2,"0").toUpperCase();


const rgbToHex = (rgb) => {
  const [r, g, b] = rgb.split(",");
  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b)
};

const getRgb = selector => window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(selector), null).getPropertyValue('background-color').match(/(\d+, \d+, \d+)/)[1]

console.log(rgbToHex(getRgb(".nhcp1")));
console.log(rgbToHex(getRgb(".nhcp2")));
console.log(rgbToHex(getRgb(".nhcp3")));
console.log(rgbToHex(getRgb(".nhcp4")));
console.log(rgbToHex(getRgb(".nhcp5")));
```

```css
.nhcp4 {
  background-color: teal
}

.nhcp5 {
  background-color: rgba(211, 0, 211, 0.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="nhcp1" style="background-color:red">Div 1</div>
<div class="nhcp2" style="background-color:blue">Div 2</div>
<div class="nhcp3" style="background-color:green">Div 3</div>
<div class="nhcp4">Div 4</div>
<div class="nhcp5">Div 5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, your

```
var nhcp1 = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".nhcp1"), null).getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

is loading a string `"rgb(x, y, z)"` into the variable `nhcp1`.

But, your function `rgbToHex(a, b, c)` expects 3 integer parameters.

So, all you need to do is extract the 3 integers from that `nhcp1` string and feed into the function.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34980657/9247555) will help you in extracting an object having the rgb values as strings.